# Nonlinear first order pde with both IC and BC

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I am trying to solve the first order problem, namely:

$$
\begin{cases}
u_{t}+uu_{x} = 0, \hspace{0.5cm} x>0, t>0 \\
u(0,t)=t, \hspace{0.5cm} t>0 \\
u(x,0)=x^2, \hspace{0.5cm} x>0
\end{cases}
$$

First I proceed as always: I introduce $U(t):=u(X(t),t)$ and write down the characteristic system:
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{dX}{dt} = U \\
\frac{dU}{dt} = 0 \hspace{0.5cm} \iff U(t)=const=U_{0}
\end{cases}
$$
thus $X(t)=U_{0}t + C$ (characteristics are straight lines), but now I have a problem. In the presence of only IC I would take $X(t)=\phi(\xi)t + \xi$ (where the $\phi$ is IC and $\xi$ is the intersection point of each of the characteristic with the $Ox$) and probably would obtain some shock there (which I would deal with the help of the R-H condition). However, in my case I have to take account of the BC as well. Do you know how should I proceed? It would be very helpful if someone could include the characteristic plane as well. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Compute the characteristics through the points $(0,\tau)$, $\tau>0$. On these characteristics, the value of $U$ is constant and equal to $\tau$, the value on $(0,\tau)$.